# Magento: preferred syntax for counting collections

Tags: magento

This may seem like a silly question, as the end result is the same but I have seen mixed uses over the framework and wondered if there was a difference, be it performance, syntactical, stylistic, or just plain programmer preference.

When counting a collection should we be using $collection->count() or count($collection)

I know why we can do both, because of the interlaces that collections implement, so I am simply asking which to use and for what reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I never benchmarked it, but using `$collection->count()` will probably be slightly more performant than `count($collection)`, since it lacks the overhead PHP needs to detect a `Countable` interface.

However, since we're talking about *nanoseconds* here, this shouldn't really matter at all.

I'd say, use whatever you like, if you're a one-man-show. But, if you're working in a team, select either one, make this a coding convention and stay with it.

Answer (score 0):

`$collection()->count()` and `count($collection)` have the same perfs. They load the entire collection and count the items...

The better way to know the number of items in a collection is `$collection->getSize()`.